# jQuery: How to submit a form without closing jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-dialog, forms, http-post

I have an html form inside a jQuery dialog.

Currently, when I click the "add" button in the form (which acts like "submit" but just adding some data checking mechanisms), the jQuery dialog will close.

But users may want to add more items, so I'd like to not close the dialog after clicking "add" button.

The following is the code snippet.

```
<head>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $( "#add_post" ).dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        width: 600
                    });
                    $( "#add_post" ).click(function() {
                        $( "#add_data" ).dialog( "open" );
                    });

                    $('#postForm').submit(function() {
                        return false;
                    });
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function checkData() {
            // always return true now
            return true;
        }

        function submitData() {
            if (checkData()) {
                document.getElementById("postForm").submit();
            }
        }
    </script>

    <input id="add_post" type="button" value="Add Post" />

    <form id="postForm" name="postForm" action="add_something" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="postUser" value="User"/>
        <input id="add_button" type="button" value="add" onclick="submitData()"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

I've read another article about not closing the dialog by adding the following

```
$('#postForm').submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

But it seems that it doesn't work.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery's ajax.

```
$('#postForm').submit(function() {

  var data = $(this).serializeArray();
  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
   $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : data,
     success:function(result){
         $("#div1").html(result);
     }});
  e.preventDefault(); 
   e.unbind(); //stop multiple form submit.
});
```

another alternative is don't use `<form>` just use button

```
$('#button').onClick(function() {

  var data = "name="+$("#txtName").val()+"&age="+$("#txtAge").val();
   $.ajax({
        url : "formController",
        type: "POST",
        data : data,
     success:function(result){
         $("#div1").html(result);
     }});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. The form will be submit successfully but the dialog will still close after submitting.